# jQuery - wait for image to load before changing background

Tags: jquery

There are lots of example of similar functionality on-line, but none seem to work for me. What I currently have is

```
<img id="sample_image" src="sample_image.png" alt="">
<script>
$('#sample_image').on('load',function(){
    $("#sample_image").css("background", "#ff0000");
});
</script>
```

I expected the image to load/show before the background color is changed, but what happens is you see the red background before the image is loaded.

I tried setting the src using jQuery...

```
<img id="sample_image" src="" alt="">
<script>
$('#sample_image').attr("src", "sample_image.png").on('load',function(){
    $("#sample_image").css("background", "<%=strRGB%>");
});
</script>
```

But this did the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the `load` method you are using for whether it's for the element or the image.

You can create a `Image` object and check for the onload

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    //change the attr here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In docs ( https://api.jquery.com/load-event/ ) they got:

```
<img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book">
...
$( "#book" ).load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

And sure, you can use vanilla:

```
var img = new Image()
img.src = "book.png";
img.onload = function(){ ... };
```

Comment: Small letters: "This method is a shortcut for .on( "load", handler )." ;-)  Use 2nd case, it realy works.

Comment: I assume in the 2nd case I need to $('#sample_image').attr("src", img.src)? If so, Its still doing the same...

Comment: I can't get this to work reliably... & the jQuery page has "Caveats of the load event when used with images". So I'm using $( window ).load(function() { to set the background & change the visibility the image once the page has loaded.

Comment: Here is the working example (and it is super reliably): http://publicscript.org/i/t.html

$( window ).load is about all the content, not image only.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but https://jsfiddle.net/8c61c21d/ shows what's happening... there is a flash of colour before the image shows. This uses slightly modified code from your publicscript.org link.

Comment: It flashs coz of image "start" to display. If you remove any javascript you will see this effect anyway.

But now I got you goal. To prevent this flash you need some animation maybe. $(img).show('fade') -- like this.